# Insert fixed a value in a joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

Here's what I want to do.

I have an empty table called "software" with the fields: key, computerID, and softwarename. I have a second table called "equipment" (which has fields equipmentID, and itemtype), and it has thousands of items, only some of which are computers (so I am trying to filter on "itemtype=computer")

```
   key|itemID      |itemname     |otherstuff
    1  |4533       |television   |blah, blah
    1  |3823       |computer     |blah, blah
    1  |1111       |couch        |blah, blah
    1  |3423       |computer     |blah, blah
    1  |1234       |computer     |blah, blah
    1  |9999       |couch        |blah, blah
    1  |8823       |computer     |blah, blah
```

I want to populate the "software" table with all the computers (computerIDs) and a fixed name, say "Windows", so that at the end I have something like this.

```
key|computerID |softwarename
1  |3823       |Windows
2  |3423       |Windows
3  |1234       |Windows
4  |3126       |Windows
5  |8823       |Windows
```

etc... for each of the 1000 computers on the list. I would then run it a couple more times for the other pieces of software that are on every computer.

All examples I can find point me at inserting rows from another, joined table, which is not what I want to do.

On a tangent, is there a really good resource that gives examples of different SQL queries and explanations? I'd really like to be a little more independent dealing with hard queries.

Thanks!

Comment: can you share the queries that you have tried

Comment: The English description and the data dump have inconsistent column names (equipmentID/itemID and itemtype/itemname). Which is correct? Also, please use [sample code](http://sscce.org) (here, SQL) for data samples, rather than ad-hoc schema.

Comment: yeah, sorry about that. I was in a rush. The tables have the correct labels, not my description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html), but have one of the columns in the `SELECT` be a constant.

```
INSERT INTO software (computerID, softwarename)
  SELECT itemID, "Windows"
    FROM equipment
    WHERE itemname='Computer'
;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is simple, and works. (and +1 for not talking down to me). By the way, any ideas on a good SQL book?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to insert rows from another table then you can try this one
for MySQL

```
SELECT @i:=@i+1  As 'Key', equipmentID as computerID, 'Windows' as softwarename
FROM equipment
WHERE itemtype='computer'
```

Comment: This one showed me the data I wanted, but didn't do the actual inserting, but then I guess you said that :)